# One-boxed content is blank in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, onebox, youtube

See the accepted answer in this question: [What happens if you choose GLaDOS' way in Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24046/9302)

There is a YouTube link at the end of the post which doesn't appear (neither the link or onebox).